# How do i make a number appear in a text box after a button is pressed?

Tags: c#, textbox, numbers, calculator

I am new to this website and fairly new to programming.

I am making a calculator in C# and I would like to know how I would make a number appear in a text box after the button for it is pressed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add code to the button event handler:

```
public void Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   TextBox1.Text = "1"; 
}
```

Which would display the `string` "1" into the Textbox.

You could also have multiple textboxes on the webpage and use:

```
public void Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string input1 = txtInput.Text;
   string input2 = txtInput2.Text;

   int userInput;
   int userInput2;
   int result;

   Int32.TryParse(input1, out userInput);
   Int32.TryParse(input2, out userInput2);

   result = userInput + userInput2;       
   txtAnswer.Text = "The answer is: " result.ToString(); 
}
```

I have included a [`TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx) example which demonstrates if the conversion from the strings to integer was successful.

Comment: You may want to have it append numbers to the text box, seeing as this program is a calculator.

Comment: @Craig - included an example.